# NLog - Allow other processes to read log file

Tags: c#, io, nlog

Starting to use NLog. The main process (a Windows service) is writing to the log file every few seconds. I need to allow another process (a desktop app) to read this file at arbitrary times (desktop app doesn't require write access).

Problem however is that NLog probably creates an exclusive lock when it opens the file for writing. So if the desktop process tries to read when the file is locked, an exception is thrown.

How can I configure NLog to allow other processes to have readonly access to the log file contents even if the main process has it open for writing? The desktop process will call `File.ReadAllText()` which I hope is safe for concurrent operations.

(I read through the docs and found that NLog even allows concurrent writing to a log file from different processes, so a read-only access should be easier in theory. I can't see any solutions though).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `File.ReadAllText()` or `File.ReadAllTextAsync()` that requires exclusive file-lock:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '...' because it is being used by another process.
```

Then I suggest using `FileShare.ReadWrite` to avoid failure when NLog is actively writing to the log-file:

```cs
using (var f = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var s = new StreamReader(f))
{
    fileContent = s.ReadToEnd();
}
```

This will also avoid issues for the application that uses NLog for writing to the log-file, as reading with exclusive lock will cause log-writing to fail with logevent being lost and bad performance.

Comment: Thanks. The post is very old and I don't even recall how I managed to fix this. Nevertheless, this a good suggestion and will help me at some other time.

Comment: @dotNET It was mostly because the question had so many views, that it seemed like a common problem for many.

Comment: @dotNET: Please consider "upvoting" and "accepting" this (most excellent!) response.

Answer (score 4):

> Problem however is that NLog probably creates an exclusive lock when it opens the file for writing

No it doesn't lock by default. There are two important settings:

ConcurrentWrites, this setting is default `true`:

> concurrentWrites - Enables support for optimized concurrent writes to same log file from multiple processes on the same machine-host, when using keepFileOpen = true. By using a special technique that lets it keep the files open from multiple processes. If only single process (and single AppDomain) application is logging, then it is faster to set to concurrentWrites = False. Boolean Default: True. Note: in UWP this setting should be false

Also there is a keepFileOpen setting, with the default on `false`

> keepFileOpen - Indicates whether to keep log file open instead of opening and closing it on each logging event. Changing this property to true will improve performance a lot, but will also keep the file handle locked. Consider setting openFileCacheTimeout = 30 when enabling this, as it will allow archive operations and react to log file being deleted. Boolean Default: False

See [docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target), there also more settings like concurrentWriteAttemptDelay, concurrentWriteAttempts etc.

Last but not least, if you're locking the file too long, maybe copy first and then read it by you application?

Comment: That's what I thought and wished were the case. However, I'm using NLog with default settings (`concurrentWrites`=`true`, `keepFileOpen`=`false`) and still get the exception "file is being used by another process". Important that the *other process* is not even trying to write to the log file, just attempting to read.

Comment: Do you get that's exception in your program reading the file or the one writing the file (with NLog)?

Comment: and what's the platform?

Comment: The one reading throws exception. The one writing is a Windows Service. The one reading is a WPF desktop application.

Comment: @dotNET Think it is the user behind the driving wheel that should read about how to open files for reading without excluding existing writers. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2967 If the file is placed on a network share, then maybe check file-share and ntfs-permissions.

Answer (score 2):

After release of version 5.0 the `keepFileOpen` is now by default set to `True`. [Reference](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html)

Comment: **Reason:** Avoid unexpected behavior caused by external applications (ex. malware scanner) suddenly taking over file handles, thus blocking the application from logging so log-events are lost. Keeping the file open also gives much better performance, than to open/close the file handle for each write.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33032325)